# Making external stylesheets in the body backwards compatible

Tags: php, css, html

**Question:**

I understand that prior to HTML5 it was invalid to include link elements with a "rel" attribute in the body tag.  Is there something I can do to maintain backwards compatibility to IE6 (without JavaScript) while still putting my stylesheets inside the body tag?  Unfortunately, maintaining functionality back to IE6 and without JavaScript are hard design specifications.

**Background:**

I am implementing a custom lightweight CMS that operates by feeding the contents of files directly into the page flow.

This means that I have to call the files in the order their content is to appear on the page.  Each file maintains control over its own output and its interactions with the object that called it, but unfortunately has no way of injecting content into the space of previously called files.

I am limited on server memory and can't afford to store page contents in variables, nor can I afford the processing time of reading through the files multiple times to pre-load stylesheets into the head element.

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score -1):

You can work with conditional states. That would be much work. But works without javascript. Example for the article-tag (this will work with anything):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><div class="article"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><article class="article"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><article class="article"><!--<![endif]-->
...
<!--[if lt IE 9]></div><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]></article><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--></article><!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.  I am asking specifically about putting link tags inside the body element.

Comment: Ok. Then the answer is: No, there is no solution for that.